# Passing ExecutionContext (flow) VS capturing it?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

From here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/

> Methods like Task.Run or ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem do this automatically. Task.Run method captures ExecutionContext from the invoking thread and stores it with the Task instance. When the TaskScheduler associated with the task runs a given delegate, it runs it via ExecutionContext.Run using the stored context.

What the difference between normal `ExecutionContext` flow and capture? To me, capture means very specific thing - a snapshot of the state of the object. Like, closure captures in anonymous methods/local methods/etc where it is generated as field and has its own value no longer reflecting the state of original value source (variable).

So when we talk about capturing context of the current thread - is this different from normal context flow? Like, during normal flow the state is always up to date so if culture on parent thread changes the child is aware, but if `EC` is captured - now the child thread just gets the snapshot of the capture of that time? Do I understand it correctly? MSDN docs are really inconsistent in the "flow"/"capture" term usage.

> Now, we have a very important observation to make: flowing ExecutionContext is semantically very different than capturing and posting to a SynchronizationContext.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/

> When you flow ExecutionContext, you’re capturing the state from one thread and then restoring that state such that it’s ambient during the supplied delegate’s execution.  That’s not what happens when you capture and use a SynchronizationContext.  The capturing part is the same, in that you’re grabbing data from the current thread, but you then use that state differently.  Rather than making that state current during the invocation of the delegate, with SynchronizationContext.Post you’re simply using that captured state to invoke the delegate.  **Where and when and how that delegate runs is completely up to the implementation of the Post method.**

This makes little sense to me. The idea behind capturing context and posting on it (in the example of UI app with UI thread) is to get back tщ that thread in the same context (to update UI, duh). But if "*Where and when and how that delegate runs is completely up to the implementation of the Post method.*" then how can you even ensure that?

Answer (score -1):

This is a notoriously complex topic and the article by Stephen Toub is (while excellent) very difficult to understand.

The ExecutionContext contains "ambient" information about the your execution environment. That is, for example the `SecurityContext` (which is kept inside the EC) will be 'flowed' which means you'll have same security context inside the threadpool thread as you do in your UI thread. It aligns a bunch of other details like this so that execution occur in the same environment.

Capturing vs flowing in this case is the difference between holding a reference to the context vs making that context the current context. So when we run something on a task like this:

```
public static void DoWork()
{

    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current; <-- SC of UI thread is captured, so a reference has been created to the SC of the UI thread
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        var scThreadPool = SynchronizationContext.Current; <-- thread pool thread has no SC associated so this is null
        … // do work on ThreadPool
        sc.Post(delegate <-- this is posting to the SC of the UI thread now
        {
            … // do work on the original context
        }, null);
   });
}
```

If you were to capture the `SynchronisationContext.Current` inside the delegate you'd get the current synchronisation context of the threadpool thread (in this it would be null since they don't have one associated).

If the synchronisation conext were to flow then we would get the UI thread SC instead of null when calling

```
var scThreadPool = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

So the execution context flows, which means it becomes the execution context of the thread pool thread but the SC doesn't. The last confusing thing is that the SC is actually part of the execution context and can (but usually doesn't) flow. In the majority of cases it won't flow and we don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I think that you are confusing the [`ExecutionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.executioncontext) with the [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext). These are two completely different things.

Comment: They are indeed, am I saying they're the same somewhere?

Comment: You are not saying that they're the same, but the OP asks about flowing the `ExecutionContext`, and your answer for the most part is about capturing the `SynchronizationContext`. Unless I am missing something, your answer seems quite irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: I thought I addressed flowing the execution context in the first half, but I suppose that might be because I wrote it :) I'll reread it and see if I can edit it to make it more clear.